# R dataframe loop to change elements of columns - if some conditions occur

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

I would need to write a code to do what follows.

The starting dataframe which is named `Tab` looks like this:

```
Rif PL1 PL2 PL3 PL4 PL5 PL6
A   0   50  50  0   50  0
B   20  20  0   20  0   0
C   30  30  30  30  30  0
D   0   40  0   40  0   0
E   0   50  0   50  0   0
```

If want to change `Tab` as follows: where value is zero (i-th position), if the value in column i-1 is equal to the value i+1, then replace zero with value of i-1 (or i+1), otherwise keep value i.

So the result should be:

```
Rif PL1 PL2 PL3 PL4 PL5 PL6
A   0   50  50  50  50  0
B   20  20  20  20  0   0
C   30  30  30  30  30  0
D   0   40  40  40  0   0
E   0   50  50  50  0   0
```

I tried the following for loop, but it doesn't work:

```
for (i in 3:6) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(Tab)) {
    if ((Tab[j,i] =0) & (Tab[j,i-1] = Tab[j,i+1])) {
      dat[j] <- Tab[j,i-1]
    } else 
      Tab[j,i]
 }
```

}

The code doesn't give any error, but produces a result different from what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `==` instead of `=`.
The former returns a logical value the latter does not.

```
for (i in 3:6) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(Tab)) {
    if ((Tab[j,i] == 0) & (Tab[j, i-1] == Tab[j, i+1])) {
      Tab[j, i] <- Tab[j, i-1]
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using matrix-subsetting instead of a for-loop:

```
A = rbind(c(0, 50,  50,  0,   50,  0),
          c(20,  20,  0,   20,  0,   0),
          c(30,  30,  30,  30,  30,  0),
          c(0,   40,  0,   40,  0,   0),
          c(0,   50,  0,   50,  0,   0))

zeros <- A == 0
AR <- cbind(-1L, A[,-ncol(A)])
AL <- cbind(A[,-1], -1L)

both <- AR == AL    
replace <- zeros & both

B <- A
B[cbind(row(A)[replace], col(A)[replace])] <- A [cbind(row(A)[replace], col(A)[replace] - 1)]

B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0   50   50   50   50    0
[2,]   20   20   20   20    0    0
[3,]   30   30   30   30   30    0
[4,]    0   40   40   40    0    0
[5,]    0   50   50   50    0    0
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

dt = read.table(text = "
Rif PL1 PL2 PL3 PL4 PL5 PL6
A   0   50  50  0   50  0
B   20  20  0   20  0   0
C   30  30  30  30  30  0
D   0   40  0   40  0   0
E   0   50  0   50  0   0
", header=T)

dt %>%
  gather(PL, value, -Rif) %>%         # reshape dataset
  group_by(Rif) %>%                   # for each Rif 
  mutate(value = ifelse(value == 0 & lag(value, default = 0) == lead(value, default = 0), 
                         lag(value), 
                         value)) %>%  # update value based on your criteria
  spread(PL, value) %>%               # reshape again
  ungroup()                           # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#   Rif     PL1   PL2   PL3   PL4   PL5   PL6
#   <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A         0    50    50    50    50     0
# 2 B        20    20    20    20     0     0
# 3 C        30    30    30    30    30     0
# 4 D         0    40    40    40     0     0
# 5 E         0    50    50    50     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

`dat` has to be a data.frame with some dimenstions i,j. If `dat` is `NULL`, it has no columns and no rows, so calling `dat[j]` is useless. I suggest creating `dat` as a copy of `Tab`, and run this code (slightly modified @Cett 's suggestion, please upvote him):

```
Rif <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
PL1 <- c(0, 20, 30, 0, 0)
PL2 <- c(50, 20, 30, 40, 50)
PL3 <- c(50, 0, 30, 0, 0)
PL4 <- c(0, 20, 30, 40, 50)
PL5 <- c(50, 0, 30, 0, 0)
PL6 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Tab <- data.frame(Rif, PL1, PL2, PL3, PL4, PL5, PL6)

dat <- Tab


for (i in 3:6) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(Tab)) {
    if ((Tab[j,i] == 0) & (Tab[j, i-1] == Tab[j, i+1])) {
      dat[j, i] <- Tab[j, i-1]
    }
  }
}

dat

> dat
  Rif PL1 PL2 PL3 PL4 PL5 PL6
1   A   0  50  50  50  50   0
2   B  20  20  20  20   0   0
3   C  30  30  30  30  30   0
4   D   0  40  40  40   0   0
5   E   0  50  50  50   0   0
>
```

Comment: Sorry! 

dat <- NULL